# How to implement Html Imports replacement using ES6 modules or any other non-obsolete technologies

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I have a few html imports, which I use to load some reusable html fragments (not necessarily html templates), below is a minimalistic example of its usage. Given Html imports are becoming [obsolete](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5144752345317376) in Chrome could anyone come up with an equivalent module based implementation?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="import" name="ImportName" href="...">
</head>

<body>
  <textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
  <script>
    document.getElementById("textarea").value = document.querySelector("link[name='ImportName']").import.body.innerHTML;
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If HTML Imports are dead/deprecated what's the best way to import your web component (X-Tag) template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37345522/if-html-imports-are-dead-deprecated-whats-the-best-way-to-import-your-web-compo)

Comment: Unfortunately flagged as duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37345522/if-html-imports-are-dead-deprecated-whats-the-best-way-to-import-your-web-compo

Comment: [Chris Coyier recently published an article covering several ways to handle this.](https://css-tricks.com/the-simplest-ways-to-handle-html-includes/)

Comment: @AlexanderNied this might work, thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to separate web components to individual files and load them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55080103/how-to-separate-web-components-to-individual-files-and-load-them)