# Any way to keep a custom elemnt's template markup and style outside of a javascript string?

Tags: javascript, html, css, templates, custom-element

This is an example of the use of custom elements from [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/customelements):

```
let tmpl = document.createElement('template');
tmpl.innerHTML = `
  <style>:host { ... }</style> <!-- look ma, scoped styles -->
  <b>I'm in shadow dom!</b>
  <slot></slot>
`;

customElements.define('x-foo-shadowdom', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super(); // always call super() first in the constructor.

    // Attach a shadow root to the element.
    let shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    shadowRoot.appendChild(tmpl.content.cloneNode(true));
  }
  ...
});
```

While this works I find this approach oddly ugly. HTML and CSS should reside in .html and .css files, not as Javascript strings.

At the same time I don’t know how to move this content to .html or .css files?

Well yes I could populate the main HTML file, namely `index.html`, with `<template>` tags for all custom elements that may be ever used – but doesn't this defeat the purpose of custom elements?

`<link rel="import">` could be promising but [it’s been dropped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/HTML_Imports).

Any other options?

(Or am I incorrect to find the original solution ugly?)

Comment: Regarding the parenthesized question, I would not say you are "incorrect" because it's a matter of opinion. To some, a complete separation of content, presentation, and interactivity (HTML, CSS, JS) is the best thing ever, but look at how popular React has become. "Everything in JS" is no longer considered to be necessarily a bad thing by many. Custom templates and scoped styles are just part of the new "it's okay people" world. But ultimately, beauty and ugliness are in the eye of the beholder. The important point is that it is now, very acceptable.

Comment: You'd have to read in the local file, then assign it to a variable, and then process it as a template. Angular does this, allowing you to keep separate HTML templates, and their associated stylesheet. While react does it as everything-is-js, I still prefer the Angular approach.

Comment: Have a look at riot.js or svelte, I like their way of writing custom-elements/components a lot better than the big ones. Let's have a look at riot's approach of including custom tags: You would add a `<script data-scr="/components/x-foo-shadowdom.html" type="custom/tag"></script>` which will NOT be fetched by the browser by default, you would then `fetch()` the custom tag manually and initialize it with as above, technically this approach should work without a framework as well.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `fetch()` to get an HTML file for your Custom Element content.

```
customElements.define('x-foo-shadowdom', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.attachShadow( {mode: 'open'} )
    }

    async connectedCallback() {
        let res = await fetch( 'x-foo.html' )
        this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = await res.text()
    }
}
```

NB: because `fetch()` and `text()` are asynchronous, you must add `async` before `connectedCallback()` and `await` before the method calls.

You can also get separate CSS content simply by using `<link>` in the HTML code.

---

> am I incorrect to find the original solution ugly?

Yes it's ugly.
If you want to use a template literal then no need to put it in a `<template>` element and clone it.

Instead, use the template literal directly:

```
shadowRoot.innerHTML =  `
  <style>:host { ... }</style> <!-- look ma, scoped styles -->
  <b>I'm in shadow dom!</b>
  <slot></slot>
`;
```

Note that there's an advantage with template literals vs separate HTML: you can use insert variables easily. Example with an incremental clic counter:

```js
customElements.define( 'click-counter', class extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    let count = 0
    let sh = this.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )    
    this.onclick = () => sh.innerHTML = `<button>${count++}</button>`
    this.click() 
  }
} )
```

```html
<click-counter></click-counter>
```