# Web components, how to separate HTML from code

Tags: web-component

I would like to know if it is possible (I am using ES6 and Typescript) to separate my HTML code from my components i.e. include the HTML code into a variable from another file.

Currently we are writing all HTML within a structure like this:

```
let html = `<h1>Hello</h1> world!`
```

Which is obviously not cool when you have a lot of HTML.

Is there a way to separate my HTML from my Javascript component so I could do for example:

```
let html = include('index.html');
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use `fetch()`. It's an asynchronous function so you'll avec to use `async/await` or Promises.

```
class MyComponent extends HTMLElement {

    async connectedCallback() {
        let res = await fetch( 'my-component.html' )

        this.innerHTML = await res.text()
    }

}
customElements.define( 'my-component', MyComponent )
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a tool to allow you to write your HTML as regular files and allow you, if you want it, to create translations that can be incorporated into each component.

It uses `rollup` to generate a compiled file that includes your JS, HTML, CSS and language info.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/component-build-tools

I am working on an upgrade that makes it simpler and does not require the combining of the files into one. I will adjust this answer once that is done.