# How to combine HTML web component with HTML file? innerHTML = foo("myfile.html")

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, html-components

With the HTML web components, I understand I can set their HTML code with:

```
this.innerHTML = `<h1></h1>`;
```

The problem I have with this is I miss out on the convenience of Emmet Abbreviation and if I'm making a lot of components, this slows me down.

I need a function which returns the HTML file as a string so I can make it equal to the innerHTML like this:

```
this.innerHTML = getHTML("myfile.hmtl");
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with `fetch()`.

Note that it's an asynchronous function so you should use `async/await` or `Promise()`.

```
this.innerHTML = await fetch( 'myfile.html' ).then( s => s.text() )
```

2 implementation examples for Web Components:

- a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58136110/4600982) with `async/await`,
- a more [complete one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55081177/4600982) with `Promise`.

Comment: Note, this will fetch the html file for every instance of the element on the page (as well as parse the HTML for every instance).