# Substituting HTML imports in Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-imports

I have the following code that uses an HTML import:

```
<script>
        function onImport() {
            $('#templates-container').append($(document.querySelector('link[rel="import"]').import).find("script"));
        }
</script>

<link rel="import" href="templates/templates.html" onload="onImport(event)" >
```

But HTML imports have been deprecated, as this warning indicates:

```
[Deprecation] HTML Imports is deprecated and will be removed in M80, around February 2020. Please use ES modules instead. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5144752345317376 and https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/07/web-components-time-to-upgrade for more details.
```

There doesn't seem to be a clean way to replace this kind of HTML import. I tried

```
<object type="text/html" data="templates/templates.html" onload="onImport(event)"></object>
```

but I get the following error:

```
indexTool.html:100 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'import' of null
    at onImport (indexTool.html:100)
    at HTMLObjectElement.onload (indexTool.html:108)
```

where the line `100` is

```
$('#templates-container').append($(document.querySelector('link[rel="import"]').import).find("script"));
```

and the line `108` is

```
<object type="text/html" data="templates/templates.html" onload="onImport(event)"></object>
```

I assume the problem is the `'link[rel="import"]'` part. What can I substitute it with?

I am using Jquery 1.11.2.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37345522/if-html-imports-are-dead-deprecated-whats-the-best-way-to-import-your-web-compo

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If HTML Imports are dead/deprecated what's the best way to import your web component (X-Tag) template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37345522/if-html-imports-are-dead-deprecated-whats-the-best-way-to-import-your-web-compo)

Comment: Thank you both, but I think I can change the import with the `<object ...` line I wrote, the question is more about how to change the Jquery function.